# Multiple_choice ListView with icon

Tags: android, android-listview, checkedtextview

I need help about ListView, I'm new at android and I must make a ListView multiple_choice (I mean will be checkbox at right) and at left there will be icon. I make the list, until select a item there is no problem. But when I chose item checkbox is won't checked. I use an adapterclass to make list with icon and use imageView and CheckedTextView. here is my code

```
public class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
private LayoutInflater mInflater; 
private Bitmap online;
private Bitmap offline;
private ArrayList<String> mCurrencyNames;
public ViewHolder holder;

public EfficientAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> mCurrencyNames) { // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time. 

    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mCurrencyNames  = mCurrencyNames;
    // Icon bound to the row. 
    online = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources (), R.drawable.markeronline);
    offline = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources (), R.drawable.markeroffline);
}

  /** * The number of items in the list is determined by the number of speeches * in our array. * * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getCount() */ 
public int getCount() {
    // return DATA.length;
    return mCurrencyNames.size(); 
}

  /** * Since the data comes from an array, just returning the index is * sufficent to get at the data. If we were using a more complex data * structure, we would return whatever object represents one row in the * list. * * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItem(int) */ 
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position; 
}


  /** * Use the array index as a unique id. * * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItemId(int) */ 
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position; 
}

  /** * Make a view to hold each row. * * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View, * android.view.ViewGroup) */ 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary calls 
    // to findViewById() on each row. 

    //When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need 
    // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied 
    // by ListView is null. 
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate (R.layout.menu_row, null);

        // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views 
        // we want to bind data to. 
        holder = new ViewHolder(); 
        holder.text = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById (R.id.text);
        holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById (R.id.icon);

        convertView.setTag(holder); 
    }
    else { 
        // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView 
        // and the ImageView. 
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
    }

    // Bind the data efficiently with the holder. 
    holder.text.setText(mCurrencyNames.get(position)); 

    String status = Friends.nodelist.get(position).getNamedItem("status").getNodeValue();
    if(status.equals("1")){
        holder.icon.setImageBitmap(online);
    }
    else
        holder.icon.setImageBitmap(offline);

    return convertView; 
}

public void refresh(ArrayList<String> list){
    mCurrencyNames = list;
}

static class ViewHolder { 
    public CheckedTextView text; 
    public ImageView icon;
}

}
```

this is my Adapter's code and I use that code for solution

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout)list.getChildAt(position);
                CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.text);
                ctv.toggle();

        }
    });
```

But after that code, when I select 4th item it makes 1st item checked. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `onClickListener` to `CheckedTextView`. It will work.

OR

Set the `CheckedTextView`'s clickable property to false.